# Signature issue with NuGet Package Manager

Tags: .net, nuget

I am trying to install NuGet on a Windows 7 machine running Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I have never used NuGet before. It is throwing this error:

> 5/28/2013 9:28:41 AM - VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The
>   signature on the update version of 'NuGet Package Manager' does not
>   match the signature on the installed version. Therefore, Extension
>   Manager cannot install the update.    at
>   VSIXInstaller.Common.VerifyMatchingExtensionSignatures(IInstalledExtension
>   installedExtension, IInstallableExtension updateExtension)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.InstallProgressPage.BeginInstallVSIX(SupportedVSSKU
>   targetAppID) 5/28/2013 9:28:41 AM - Install Error :
>   VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The signature on the update
>   version of 'NuGet Package Manager' does not match the signature on the
>   installed version. Therefore, Extension Manager cannot install the
>   update.    at
>   VSIXInstaller.Common.VerifyMatchingExtensionSignatures(IInstalledExtension
>   installedExtension, IInstallableExtension updateExtension)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.InstallProgressPage.BeginInstallVSIX(SupportedVSSKU
>   targetAppID)

Does this error mean that NuGet is already installed on my machine? (Maybe for a prior user?) What steps can I take to debug this problem? I'm not really sure where to go from here.

I could not find this problem on the [known issues](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply uninstall NuGet first and make a clean install.

Sometime in the past, the signature has been changed causing this problem.

BTW: The very first problem on the known issues page refers to your exact problem.